# loader.asp loading small files but not large files

Tags: asp-classic

Hi I have a problem  with uploading files to my server through an admin system.  I myself do not really work with ASP scripting much, so I don't understand the problem.

When uploading files like thumbnails there seems to be no problem with the script, but when trying to upload the bigger images it does not work and gives me an Internal server error 500 (There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.)

The loading script that is used is call LOADER.ASP and as said before using small files, the script uploads fine and all entries are made into the the database just fine.

If anyone could just give me a hint to why this might happen or what could be the cause for giving the error it woulds realy help

Thank you

Comment: have you verified it's not a server limitation for file size uploads?

Comment: I have used a different script called freeaspupload and that allows me to to upload bigger file, but i can't integrate it with the rest of the script, as I said i don't really understand ASP that well.

Comment: show some code and someone might be able to help you better. Also can you identify where the file size limit is? you might be able to track through the code to figure out where it's limiting it.

Comment: loader.asp is freescript on the web:  http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2001042501&page=2

Comment: "Internal server error 500" does not actually describe what the real problem is. Try to search through the IIS log files for a more descriptive error message, or log on to the server and surf to the website using 'localhost'; Then the server should tell the exact cause of the error.